# Wifi problems with HP Stream

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, broadcom

My wireless model is:

According to the label: BCM943142Y

According to lspci: BCM43142 (rev 01)

My network adapter's ID is: 14e4:4365 (rev 01)

`bcmwl-kernel-source` is installed, and the Ubuntu software thing says that my WiFi device `wlo1` is using it. This is the correct driver.

Connecting to my phone hotspot works fine, so I am able to access the internet with it. I only get so much data though, and it's very slow. It fails to connect to all other networks here at my university and in my dorm. Looking through `syslog`, it gives up connecting when it times out, saying that it failed to get IP configuration. I had windows before, and the WiFi worked flawlessly.

I'm not even sure if this is the right log, or the right part of the log, but here is something in `/var/log/syslog` that looks relevent:

```
 16:03:41 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126621.6967] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
 16:03:41 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126621.6976] manager: startup complete
 16:03:41 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126621.7042] device (wlo1): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available') [20 30 42]
 16:03:42 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126622.7214] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: ready -> inactive
 16:03:45 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126625.5612] device (wlo1): Activation: starting connection '4B' (74c9262b-16e7-4344-a3e8-0bbe32aad962)
 16:03:45 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126625.5617] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="74c9262b-16e7-4344-a3e8-0bbe32aad962" name="4B" pid=1706 uid=1000 result="success"
 16:03:45 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126625.5624] device (wlo1): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
 16:03:45 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126625.5627] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
 16:03:45 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126625.5650] device (wlo1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
 16:03:45 whoopsie[820]: [16:03:45] offline
 16:03:45 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126625.5760] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) connection '4B' requires no security.  No secrets needed.
 16:03:45 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126625.5764] Config: added 'ssid' value '4B'
 16:03:45 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126625.5764] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
 16:03:45 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126625.5765] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'NONE'
 16:03:45 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126625.5807] sup-iface[0x28868c0,wlo1]: config: set interface ap_scan to 1
 16:03:45 wpa_supplicant[1009]: wlo1: Trying to associate with 80:2a:a8:5a:b4:12 (SSID='4B' freq=2462 MHz)
 16:03:45 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126625.6103] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: inactive -> associating
 16:03:45 wpa_supplicant[1009]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT status_code=16
 16:03:45 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126625.6688] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
 16:03:45 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126625.7719] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
 16:03:46 wpa_supplicant[1009]: wlo1: Trying to associate with 80:2a:a8:5a:b4:38 (SSID='4B' freq=2462 MHz)
 16:03:46 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126626.7284] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
 16:03:46 wpa_supplicant[1009]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT status_code=16
 16:03:46 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126626.7624] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
 16:03:46 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126626.8650] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
 16:03:47 wpa_supplicant[1009]: wlo1: Trying to associate with 82:2a:a8:5a:b3:ca (SSID='4B' freq=2437 MHz)
 16:03:47 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126627.8086] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
 16:03:47 wpa_supplicant[1009]: wlo1: Associated with 82:2a:a8:5a:b3:ca
 16:03:47 wpa_supplicant[1009]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 82:2a:a8:5a:b3:ca completed [id=0 id_str=]
 16:03:47 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126627.9093] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associating -> completed
 16:03:47 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126627.9095] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network '4B'.
 16:03:47 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126627.9100] device (wlo1): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
 16:03:47 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126627.9429] dhcp4 (wlo1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
 16:03:47 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126627.9508] dhcp4 (wlo1): dhclient started with pid 2161
 16:03:48 dhclient[2161]: DHCPDISCOVER on wlo1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x4aa57d69)
 16:03:49 avahi-daemon[816]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv6 with address fe80::3def:7c56:fc12:6dc6.
 16:03:49 avahi-daemon[816]: New relevant interface wlo1.IPv6 for mDNS.
 16:03:49 avahi-daemon[816]: Registering new address record for fe80::3def:7c56:fc12:6dc6 on wlo1.*.
 16:03:51 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126631.0683] manager: WiFi hardware radio set enabled
 16:03:51 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126631.0685] manager: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
 16:03:51 dhclient[2161]: DHCPDISCOVER on wlo1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x4aa57d69)
 16:03:58 dhclient[2161]: DHCPDISCOVER on wlo1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0x4aa57d69)
 16:04:08 dhclient[2161]: DHCPDISCOVER on wlo1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21 (xid=0x4aa57d69)
 16:04:29 dhclient[2161]: DHCPDISCOVER on wlo1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 18 (xid=0x4aa57d69)
 16:04:33 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126673.0701] dhcp4 (wlo1): request timed out
 16:04:33 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126673.0703] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed unknown -> timeout
 16:04:33 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126673.0909] dhcp4 (wlo1): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 2161
 16:04:33 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126673.0911] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed timeout -> done
 16:04:33 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126673.0943] device (wlo1): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
 16:04:33 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126673.0972] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
 16:04:33 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126673.1030] device (wlo1): Activation: failed for connection '4B'
 16:04:33 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126673.1118] device (wlo1): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
 16:04:33 avahi-daemon[816]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::3def:7c56:fc12:6dc6 on wlo1.
 16:04:33 avahi-daemon[816]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv6 with address fe80::3def:7c56:fc12:6dc6.
 16:04:33 avahi-daemon[816]: Interface wlo1.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
 16:04:33 wpa_supplicant[1009]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=82:2a:a8:5a:b3:ca reason=3 locally_generated=1
 16:04:33 wpa_supplicant[1009]: nl80211: Was expecting local disconnect but got another disconnect event first
 16:04:33 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126673.1453] sup-iface[0x28868c0,wlo1]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
 16:04:33 NetworkManager[2137]:   [1490126673.1485] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
 16:04:33 wpa_supplicant[1009]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
 16:06:51 wpa_supplicant[1009]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=US
```

Please help.

Comment: This is a question for Chili555 or Pilot6

Comment: @AndroidDev What should I do if this doesn't get answered? I feel like I'm close, I'm feel like it's the configuration of the dorm's network that is causing the issue, I just don't know how to configure my end. Or it's a different problem entirely, I don't know. I was able to get WICD to work on this network sometimes before I reinstalled ubuntu 16.04, but usually it did the same thing that's happening now.